# Setting up ssh server on Ubuntu dektop

Tags: ubuntu, ssh

I'm setting up a ssh server on 10.10(soon to be 11.04) desktop. I'm sure this goes without saying but, I want it to be as simple and secure as possible. I only plan to connect from one other Ubuntu machine. I have a few starter questions -

`ssh-keygen -t dsa` will create a key.

- I then simply attach(cat) that key to the end of the authorized_keys2 file on the remote computer?
- That is secure?
- What is the difference between the public and private key?

  - How do I get the sshd daemon to start at startup? I'd like to run this headless without X starting.
  - How can I easily start and stop an X session?

references - https://help.ubuntu.com/8.04/serverg...sh-server.html
and https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SS...dvancedOpenSSH

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think you're making the SSH component harder than it needs to be.

On the remote machine (ssh server) you do:

```
# apt-get install ssh
```

This installs ssh, sets it to start on bootup, and starts it up *right then*

Then you do, on the client machine:

```
$ ssh-keygen
```

Answer, the questions when prompted. Then do

```
$ ssh-copy-id <user>@<ssh server>
```

Where `<username>` is the user you want to authenticate as with your key, and `<ssh server>` is the ip address/host/dns of the SSH server you want to add your key too. Then test it!

```
$ ssh <user>@<ssh server>
```

Now that you're in you want to get root perms...

```
$ sudo su
```

And, now that you've got root perms, edit `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`

```
# vim /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

Assuming you know basic vim of course… Now, change the line that reads

```
PasswordAuthentication yes
```

To

```
PasswordAuthentication no
```

That's it for setting up SSH on an Ubuntu machine. Now only you can get into it with your key.

Comment: @Evan Carroll Hey also, opening up the ssh port on my router is safe as long as I require a password/key, correct?

Comment: It's safe, yes. To be even more safe move the SSH port to something other than the default.

Comment: @Evan - excellent exposition of this.

Comment: @Amazed that doesn't actually make it more safe, that just obscures it.

Comment: @Evan Carroll perhaps so, but I doubt you'd find anyone who would say that from a security perspective leaving ssh on the default port is better than moving it.

Comment: @Amazed, I doubt you would find anyone from the security sector who would advise changing ports. Look here is the deal when it comes to moving ports -- you're solving nothing, create more work for yourself, and failing to address the real concerns. It's the same logic that you almost *have* to use to work in security and use Microsoft products. Our arguments don't have to sink quite that low. Also keep in mind, SSH responds TCP sockets revealing its identity see `nc <server> <port>` for proof, so you're always one small sweep away from revealing the port.

Comment: Looking at my own auth.log file from before and after moving from the default port seems to support the idea that moving it was a good thing. Before: 423 attacks per day(average); after: 0 per day(absolute.)

Comment: But you're defining "attacks" as totally autonomous scripts targeting the default port probably just trying to bruteforce your password. Make those "attacks" target the non-default port... Are you more secure? Or, better yet, disable passwordauth and ignore them entirely. You can't bruteforce an rsa/dsa key.

Answer (score 1):

There are two commands you must give. The first installs and sets up SSH, the second tests the setup:

1. sudo apt-get install ssh
2. ssh localhost

Here is a more detailed explanation. On the server:

1. Open up a terminal window
2. Type **apt-get install ssh** and answer Y when prompted to install. Note that **SSH2 RSA** and **DSA** keys are created automatically as part of the install.
3. Test the install by typing **ssh localhost**. That command starts an SSH session on the current machine. The RSA fingerprint is displayed along with a query asking if you want to continue. Answer **yes** to connect. After doing this I popped over to a windows machine and easily used Putty to connect to my Ubuntu server.

Answer (score 0):

The private key is exactly that- private. Put a passphrase on it, and don't give anyone access to it. The public key is the one that you push to the servers that you want to access.